# Network communication with Stripe failed - Google App Engine Python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x, stripe-payments

We have a call to Stripe from our App Engine application. App engine is Standard, Python 3.7

The requirements.txt is as follows

```
jinja2
pytz
stripe
flask
google-cloud-firestore==1.9.0
```

We are making a stripe call function like this

```
        stripe.api_key = self.stripe_api_key
       
        payment_intent_response = stripe.PaymentIntent.create(
            payment_method_types    = payment_method_types_array,
            amount                  = payment_amount,
            currency                = payment_currency,
            stripe_account                = {stripe_account_id})
```

When we execute the above code we get the error "Network communication with Stripe failed". Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You should run the Stripe [reachability tool](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-reachability) to check that your server is able to reach Stripe's API, in particular you'll need to ensure you can reach [these IP addresses](https://stripe.com/docs/ips#ips). Your network may be blocking egress and preventing proper functioning of the client.

Comment: But our application is in Google App Engine. We are able to make other Stripe API calls like stripe.Customer.create_source(stripe_customer_id, source=bank_account_token) without any problem.

Comment: If this is an intermittent error, you can look at setting up automatic retries: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-python#configuring-automatic-retries